# How to close next element with specify class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have two panels. For thoes of two panels i have two opening buttons. So, when i click at first button my first panel is opened. Everything's fine. But now, when i need to open next panel i want to close this first. So that the two panels were not open at the same time. I don't want to add separated classes for those, want to only use `opened` class. This is my code and thx for help:

```
$('.js-sp-closing-button.opened').live('click', function(){
    if($(this).next.next('.js-scrolling-list').hasClass('opened_panel')){
       $(this).removeClass('opened_panel')
    }
});

<span class="top_ticker_small_02 js-sp-closing-button opened">All</span>
<div class="pp_elements js-scrolling-list opened_panel">...</div>
...
<span class="top_ticker_small_02 js-sp-closing-button">All</span>
<div class="pp_elements js-scrolling-list">...</div>
```

Comment: There is a typo ".next.next('.js-scrolling-list')" and please set a jsfiddle

Comment: ok, but after first opening button i have first opened panel, but i need to close the text opened panel after this default opened panel

Comment: When posting questions like this be sure to include your markup as well

Comment: i'v add my html, the first panel is in opened state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to the issue with the opening and closing panels, why not just close all of the panels prior to opening a new one.  Something like:

```
$('.js-sp-closing-button.opened').live('click', function(){
    //Close all panels
    $('.js-scrolling-list').removeClass('opened_panel');
    /** Code to open next panel **/
});
```

Also, `.next` is a method, you need to use parenthesis to call it.

```
$('.js-sp-closing-button.opened').live('click', function(){
    if($(this).next().next('.js-scrolling-list').hasClass('opened_panel')){
       $(this).removeClass('opened_panel')
    }
});
```

Depending on your intentions the two calls to .next() may be unnecessary.  If the two panels are siblings one call to .next() which specifies a selector `.js-scrolling.list` is all you would need.

**Example**:

```
$('.js-sp-closing-button.opened').live('click', function(){
    if($(this).next('.js-scrolling-list').hasClass('opened_panel')){
       $(this).removeClass('opened_panel')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You `missed the next parenthesis`, .next.next( would be .next().next(. `You can pass class name to next function instead of having two next function` calls, *if you are not intentionally skipping element.*

```
$('.js-sp-closing-button.opened').live('click', function(){
    if($(this).next().next('.js-scrolling-list').hasClass('opened_panel')){
       $(this).removeClass('opened_panel')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Far easier just to do this...

```
$('.js-scrolling-list').live('click', function(){

    $('.js-scrolling-list').removeClass('opened_panel');
    $(this).addClass('opened_panel');

});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/snKM8/2/

Comment: thx, you inspired me, and i'v add some corrects, but it's corect perfect

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I managed to get, work's good - maybe someone will be benefit in future. 
Thx for all of you guys:

```
$('.js-sp-closing-button').live('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')){
        $('.js-sp-closing-button').removeClass('opened');
        $(this).addClass('opened');
        $('.js-scrolling-list').removeClass('opened_panel');
        $(this).next('div').addClass('opened_panel');
    } else {
        $('.js-sp-closing-button').removeClass('opened');
        $(this).next('div').removeClass('opened_panel');
        $(this).removeClass('opened');
    }
});
```